# Is ISRO Making a Methane Engine?

Tags: isro, cryogenics, methane, development

I'd read some stray comment on the internet claiming that ISRO is working on a methane-LOX engine, just as a technology demonstrator. Is this true?

Comment: http://indico.vecc.gov.in/indico/contributionDisplay.py?contribId=72&sessionId=13&confId=44 - This site says "Methane has been chosen as the next generation cryogenic fluid for its certain advantages over liquid hydrogen and kerosene." I'm looking for more details.

Comment: Unfortunately, the above is the only seemingly official statement I could find on it.